# Contour Integral of $\frac {1}{1+z^2}$ over $\delta B(0,2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

My next question about contour integrals is: 
Is it true that:

$$\int_{\delta B(0,2)} \frac{1}{1+z^2}dz = \int_{\delta B(0,2)} \frac{\frac{z}{1+z^2}}{z} dz = \left[ 2\pi i \frac{z}{1+z^2}\right]_{z=0} = 0  $$
I tried to apply cauchys integral formula but i think $\frac{z}{1+z^2}$ isn't regular in $B(0,2)$. So i tried another way to solve this: Let $\gamma : [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{C}, \gamma(t) = 2\exp(it), \; \gamma(0) = 2,\; \gamma(2\pi) = 2$.
$$\int_{\delta B(0,2)} \frac{1}{1+z^2}dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{2i\exp(it)}{1+(2\exp(it))^2}dt = \dots = \left[ \arctan(2\exp(it))\right]_{t=0}^{2\pi} = 0$$
I learned earlier that this way should be prefered because of the incontinuity of $\arctan$. However wolframalpha tells me the integral is zero. So i wonder if there is another way i could try without using the continuity of $\arctan$.

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula does work on this function, you can find the residues and then sum them to obtain zero as they both lie inside the contour considered and are opposite in parity

Comment: ok, in my course we didnt talk about residues yet so is there another way without residues ?

Comment: The provided answer beat me to it but that's how I would have done it without residues :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Once again use the partial fraction decomposition

$$\frac{1}{1+z^2}=-\frac{\mathrm i}{2}\frac{1}{z-\mathrm i}+\frac{\mathrm i}{2}\frac{1}{z+\mathrm i}$$

thus you can rewrite one integral in a domain with two singularities into two integrals which have only one singularity in their domain. Since our most beloved integral in complex analysis yields $$\oint_{\partial B_\rho(a)}\frac{1}{z-a}=2\pi\mathrm i$$ you might quickly see why the integral over $1/(1+z^2)$ along $\partial B_2(0)$ vanishes.